# Get Variable form partial class selector jQuery

Tags: jquery

How would you store the remaining part of a class selector as a variable for a foreach loop

for example:

```
<div class="sel_child1">something</div>
<div class="sel_child2">something</div>
```

i know i can sect with:

```
jQuery( "[class^='sel_']" )
```

but i need the remainder for the foreach loop because the second part of the class is the child element to target and before you ask i know i should use a data attribute or another method but the CMS i am using wont let me.

it is also possible that the div has additional unrelated classes.

Comment: split the class name and use each part sa needed

Comment: Thanks guradio but not knowing what additional classes could be on the div i think i need a method that is more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the entire string of classes using the `.attr("class")` method. From there it's a matter of breaking it into a list of classes, finding the one that starts with `"sel_"`, and storing the second piece.

```js
$("[class*='sel_']").each(function() {     //match all classes with sel_ in them
  const child = $(this)         
    .attr("class")                         //get the class string
    .split(" ")                            //break it into individual classes
    .find(n => n.startsWith("sel_"))       //find the one that starts with sel_
    .split("_")[1];                        //split it on _ and take the second piece

  console.log(child);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sel_child1 unrelated">something</div>
<div class="unrelated sel_child2">something</div>
```

And a more concise RegEx alternative...

```js
$("[class*='sel_']").each(function() {
  const child = $(this).attr("class").match(/(?:^|\s)sel_([^\s]*)/)[1];
  console.log(child);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sel_child1 unrelated">something</div>
<div class="unrelated sel_child2 xsel_child3">something</div>
```

---

<sup>**RegEx Reference**</sup>

<sup>`(?:^|\s)` - start of string **or** a space (non-capture)</sup>

<sup>`sel_` - "sel_"</sup>

<sup>`([^\s]*)` - everything until the next space (capture)</sup>

Comment: I don't know who can put a downvote for this answer. it is great way to get the remaining part as the OP requirement

Comment: @MitchellBray Happy to help. Please note that at the time of your comment, the regex solution was matching any class that *contained* `sel_` as opposed to classes that *start with* `sel_`. The answer has been updated to address/resolve this.